# Why the result of descriptor.field_count() is different?

Tags: c++, qt, reflection, protocol-buffers, descriptor

I'm using protobuf in Qt platform. function A and B are slot functions：

```
function A : void MainWindow::pushButton_load_clicked();
function B : void MainWindow::listWidget_LBM_itemClicked(QListWidgetItem *item);
dic : QHash<QString, const Message*> dic;
```

In function A, I store the pointer to Message to a hashtable.

```
for (auto message_ptr : res)
{
   // ...
   dic[funcid] = message_ptr;
}
```

In function B, I get the pointer to Message and use protobuf API to get the number of fields in the Message.

```
// ...
if(dic.find(funcid) == dic.end())
{
   qDebug() << "funcid " << funcid << " does not exist in dic" << endl;
   return;
}
const Message* message_ptr = dic[funcid];
const Descriptor* desc = message_ptr->GetDescriptor();
qDebug() << "funcid is : " << funcid << "desc->field_count() : " << desc->field_count() << endl;
```

But when I call function B for several times, the result of descriptor->field_count() is different. the output is:

```
funcid is :  "30001" desc->field_count() :  0 

funcid is :  "30007" desc->field_count() :  6881390
```

the correct answer is 16 and 5.

I have tried to test whether the two pointers to Descriptor of one Message in function A and function B are the same. The answer is yes.

```
const Message* m1,m2,m3;
const Descriptor* d1,*d2,*d3;
int cnt = 0;
int f1, f2, f3;

function A:
dic[funcid] = message_ptr;
if(cnt == 0)
{
     m1 = message_ptr;
     d1 = m1->GetDescriptor();
     f1 = d1->field_count();
     ++cnt;
}
else if(cnt == 1)
{
     m2 = message_ptr;
     d2 = m2->GetDescriptor();
     f2 = d2->field_count();
     ++cnt;
}
else
{
     m3 = message_ptr;
     d3 = m3->GetDescriptor();
     f3 = d3->field_count();
}

function B:
const Message * message_ptr = dic[funcid];
if(funcid == "30007")
{
    auto d = message_ptr->GetDescriptor();
    if(message_ptr == m1)
        qDebug() << "equals m1" << endl;
    else
        qDebug() << "not equals m1" << endl;
    if(d == d1)
        qDebug() << "equals d1" << endl;
    else
        qDebug() << "not equals d1" << endl;
    if(d->field_count() == f1)
        qDebug() << "equals f1" << endl;
    else
        qDebug() << "not equals f1" << endl;
}
else if(funcid == "30001")
{
    auto d = message_ptr->GetDescriptor();
    if(message_ptr == m2)
        qDebug() << "equals m2" << endl;
    else
        qDebug() << "not equals m2" << endl;
    if(message_ptr->GetDescriptor() == d2)
        qDebug() << "equals d2" << endl;
    else
        qDebug() << "not equals d2" << endl;
    if(d->field_count() == f2)
        qDebug() << "equals f2" << endl;
    else
        qDebug() << "not equals f2" << endl;
}
else
{
    auto d = message_ptr->GetDescriptor();
    if(message_ptr == m3)
        qDebug() << "equals m3" << endl;
    else
        qDebug() << "not equals m3" << endl;
    if(message_ptr->GetDescriptor() == d3)
        qDebug() << "equals d3" << endl;
    else
        qDebug() << "not equals d3" << endl;
    if(d->field_count() == f3)
        qDebug() << "equals f3" << endl;
    else
        qDebug() << "not equals f3" << endl;
}
```

the output is :

```
equals m1 

equals d1 

not equals f1 

equals m2 

equals d2 

not equals f2 

equals m3 

equals d3 

equals f3
```

Does anyone know the reason?
Thanks in advance.

I'm expecting to get the correct result of descriptor->field_count() in function B.

Comment: 1) Do not post pictures.  Post text.  2) What exactly is `dic`?

Comment: 1) now is text 2) QHash<QString, const Message*> dic @PaulMcKenzie

Comment: `const Message * message_ptr = dic_funcid_mp[funcid];` -- What happens to `dic_funcid_mp` if `funcid` does not exist?  According to the [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qhash.html#operator-5b-5d), a new entry is inserted.

Comment: directly end the function B. In my test, the funcid always exists.

Comment: No, that is not what I am referring to.  For `operator []`, if the item does not exist, `QHash` inserts an empty element.  So that means for every time that test fails, you are growing the map with empty entries.

Comment: Sorry, My code is not complete. I have updated the function B in my question.

Comment: To me all the results seem garbage, unless you really have `0` or `6881390` fields in a message. So the pointer is probably invalid, and then it doesn't help that it stays the same.

Comment: Yes,  you are right. The protobuf API  says the pointer to google::protobuf::Descriptor stored in a global hashtable is invalid in some degree.@jpa

Comment: reference: https://protobuf.dev/reference/cpp/api-docs/google.protobuf.dynamic_message/#DynamicMessageFactory